# When marshaling a COM interface to multiple threads, is cloning the stream sufficient, or is copying it necessary?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, com

According to [Raymond's guide](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151022-00/?p=91301), when marshaling a COM interface to multiple threads, you must "[t]ransmit a *copy* of the stream to each of the threads you want to share the object with." (Or you could use a mutex, but let's set that option aside for now.)

I was wondering if using `IStream::Clone` will suffice for that purpose, or whether that doesn't count as a copy.

Also, if `IStream::Clone` is fine, I was wondering if you need to call it from the thread that created the original stream, or if one of the background threads can call it.  I'm wondering whether, if a background thread called it, you'd wind up with the exact situation we're trying to avoid in the first place (sharing COM pointers across threads).

Thank you for any info.

Comment: Not starting with Windows 8.1, you just need Ro­Get­Agile­Reference (in the same process).

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, I tried `Ro­Get­Agile­Reference` on Windows 8.1, but I received `E_NOTIMPL`.

Comment: @SimonMourier `RoGetAgileReference()` can be used to marshal an interface pointer to a thread. But it does not make a separate copy of that interface for multiple threads to use.

Comment: what sense pass object to **multiple** threads ? so really pass the same task several time to pool ? almost 100% this is design error

Comment: @RbMm Then why would Raymond provide instructions on how to do it?  And why does `MSHLFLAGS_TABLE­STRONG` exist?

Comment: i speak about concrete task - what sense post the **same** task to multiple threads ?! this is absolute unrelated to `MSHLFLAGS_TABLE­STRONG`

Comment: @RbMm Well I'm not posting the same task to multiple threads -- just the same object.

Comment: yes, same object - and what sense in this ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, without using a synchronizing mutex, you would need to [`Clone()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-istream-clone) the original stream for each thread, that way each clone has its own read/write seek position that is independent of the other clones.

> The Clone method **creates a new stream object with its own seek pointer** that references the same bytes as the original stream.

Raymond's guide even eludes to this:

> Transmit a copy of the stream to each of the threads you want to share the object with. (**You need to use a copy so that the multiple threads don’t all try to use the same stream and step on each other’s stream position**. Alternatively, you could be clever and use the same stream, but use a mutex or other synchronization object to make sure only one thread uses the stream at a time.)

Comment: Thanks. Do you need to call `IStream::Clone` from the thread that created the original stream, or can one of the background threads call it?  I'm wondering if a background thread called it, then you'd wind up with the exact situation we're trying to avoid in the first place -- sharing COM pointers across threads.

Comment: @user15284017 it would be safer for the original thread to create the clones and pass them to each thread. Otherwise you indeed have a race condition if the threads try to create their own clones.